# Setting up PyCharm in Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I come from R and now try to use python to solve some problems... I decided to use PyCharm IDE due to many recommendations on the internet. But I got problems, setting this up on Windows 10. I downloaded the community-Version of PyCharm and installed it. I set up a new project with a virtual enviroment (default).

But how to install packages? I tried "pip install pandas" in console, but it says that pip is unknown.
I searched on the internet, but even "python --version" does not work. Then I tried File -> Setting -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> "+" -> Search "pandas" -> Install Package but it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'"... so I tried the same with "Cython" but then it says "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"

It seems that somehow Windows and Python are not working together... What am I doing wrong? My Interpreter is Python 3.8

I hope you can help me!

Scarbyard

Comment: `python --version` doesn't work?? Did you actually install python and have the directory in path environment variable?

Comment: From your description python isn't included in the Win10 environment variable PATH. You can add it manually for testing (try both user and administrator, it's been my experience user account might bug out). Afterwards, within PyCharm go to File->Settings->Project and you'll find a PIP interface there that you can use for convenience setting up a venv with it...(During installation PyCharm should give you the option to add Python to Win10 Path, for simplicity you might want to try that.)

Comment: Ok, finally I managed to set up an venv and installed some packages... is this the recommended way? To set up a new venv for each project and install pandas, etc. each time again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several issues with PyCharm and as a fan of RStudio, I can recomment Anaconda-Installation with the Spyder IDE for a simple start into Python!

The Spyder-IDE can even be set to RStudio-layout, which is very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Open Project->File->Settings->Project Interpreter
- See that the correct Interpreter is selected
- Packages that have been installed should populate the screen
- '+' at the top right of the list brings up the 'Available Packages' screen
- Search for the package
- 'Install Package' on the bottom left should do the work

This is assuming that your virtual environment was set up and activated.

I use the Pycharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin and can create and activate envs as well as install packages from Pycharm or Anaconda(separate download).

Oh -- Anaconda is still @ 3.7 so reinstall might be the cleanest way if you choose the Anaconda option.